# Add upload attachment name into textarea before submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

Any method i can add the filename into textarea before the user submit the form?

Is it possible to do it by php / javascript? Thank you.

```html
    <form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
    <p><select name="txtLeaveType" id="txtLeaveType">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">AL</option>
    <option value="2">SL</option>
    </select></p>

    <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
    <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, by using javascript :

add onchange event on input:file, so we can track the event

```
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
    <p><select name="txtLeaveType" id="txtLeaveType">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">AL</option>
    <option value="2">SL</option>
    </select></p>

    <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
    <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" onchange="takeName(event)" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

and use this javascript code

```
<script>
        function takeName(event) {
            let filename = event.path[0].files[0].name;
            document.getElementById("txtComment").value = filename;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This work for me.
How can i add something before and after the file name?
such as:
<a href="http://google.com/filename.jpg"/>filename.jpg</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for doing it.

```js
document.getElementById('fileToUpload').addEventListener('change', openDialog);
function openDialog(e)
{
    var file_name = e.target.files[0].name;
    document.getElementById("txtComment").value = file_name;
}
```

```html
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
<p><select name="txtLeaveType" id="txtLeaveType">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">AL</option>
<option value="2">SL</option>
</select></p>

<p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
<p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```js
            let imageUpload = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
            let outputText =  document.getElementById("txtComment");
            imageUpload.onchange = function () {
                let input = this.files[0];
                if (input) {
                    outputText.value = input.name;
                }
            }
```

```html
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
        <p><select name="txtLeaveType" id="txtLeaveType">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">AL</option>
                <option value="2">SL</option>
            </select></p>
    
        <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
        <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
```

```
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
        <p><select name="txtLeaveType" id="txtLeaveType">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">AL</option>
                <option value="2">SL</option>
            </select></p>
    
        <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
        <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let imageUpload = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
            let outputText =  document.getElementById("txtComment");
            imageUpload.onchange = function () {
                let input = this.files[0];
                if (input) {
                    outputText.value = input.name;
                }
            }
        </script>
```